# Undefined method index_path, Rails 4.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, undefined

I'm a newbie on Rails, and I'm stuckin' on a problem that I really don't understand.

I've a resource (resources :proposta) in my app that is my app index too. Those are my snippets:

Routes.rb

```
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  resources :proposta
  root 'proposta#index'
```

proposta_controller.rb

```
class PropostaController < ApplicationController
  def index
    @proposta = Proposta.new
  end
end
```

and that line in my view views/proposta/index.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @proposta, html: {class: 'registration-form'} do |p| %>
```

But when I access my index (localhost:3000/), I receive the following error:

```
Showing /Users/sergio/RubymineProjects/habite/app/views/proposta/index.html.erb where line #155 raised: undefined method `proposta_index_path' for #< <Class:0x007febf4675600>:0x007febf43dca38>
```

What should I do?

Comment: look at your "rake routes" to see if you have a route called "proposta_index_path". Also check if their verb is "GET" and you are requesting this verb. If possible, can I ask you to edit your answer and put the results of "rake routes" and also the line 155 of the "app/views/proposta/index.html.erb"?

Comment: You are likely to run into issues with Rails' pluralizer by using nouns from your native language. More than that, you might have *already* run. Better use english identifiers until you're absolutely sure about what's happening. Yet, to start with, run `rake routes` and show the output.

Comment: I`ve changed for propostas but didn`t work. It seems it`s not an pluralizer issue.

Comment: I don't know if this error is related to a pluralizer issue (I think isn't),  although you must to change your `config/initializers/inflections.rb` and put an `inflect.plural 'proposta', 'propostas'` and also a `inflect.singular 'propostas', 'proposta'` in order of Rails do a proper plural handling (for example, your controller file name should be in plural - `propostas_controller.rb`, your class should be `PropostasController`, and so on).

Answer (score 0):

Change app/views/proposta/index.html.erb line 55 `proposta_index_path` to `propostas_path`

and change routes from `resources :proposta` to `resources :propostas` and root
should now look like: `root 'propostas#index'`

Comment: Didn`t solved. Altough, there`s no proposta_index_path on line 155.

Answer (score 0):

As D-side and Daniel Loureiro said, the problem was with plural words on my local lang. I`ve corrected this with the following code:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.plural 'proposta', 'propostas'
  inflect.singular 'propostas', 'proposta'
end
```

Then, I`ve made rake db:migrate and everything went ok. Thanks guys!